# Image download output does not save all images in a specific folder

Tags: python, image, loops, directory, file-handling

I've been working the last couple of weeks on a image downloader from the site mangareader and I've finally done the main code, except from a small bug, which makes the first image to save itself outside the folder the code creates to save them all. Here's an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUpg8.png

I can't figure out why it works this way, since the code seemed to be working just fine. Here's the function that makes the folder change:

```
def pathchange(old, new):
    if os.path.exists(new):
        os.chdir(new)
    else:
        os.mkdir(new)
```

And here is the download function: http://pastebin.com/FfuxirvK

Thanks beforehand for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the path does not exist, you make the folder but forget to change to it. This is why the first image is not with the rest.

I suggest this simple fix:

```
def pathchange(old, new):
    if not(os.path.exists(new)):
        os.mkdir(new)
    os.chdir(new)
```

Also, it seems the `old` argument doesn't serve any function.